# PHP to C# conversion. Taking user input / manipulating user input

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am required to learn C#/ASP.NET.  I have been googling but I can't find any tutorial.

Right now I have an HTML form in ASP.NET

How do I manipulate the user input and display them back?

In PHP I would write this:

```
if (isset($_POST['fname'])){
$name = $_POST['fname'];

echo $name;
}
```

How do I do the same in  C#/ ASP.NET?

Comment: You have Googled but have not found *any* tutorial? The first result I found for "asp.net forms tutorial" is the [official webforms tutorial page](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials).

Comment: Or this one http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/

Comment: Correction: I don't know it is ASP.NET or C#. I have been googling both. Are they the same thing? @_@
Because I know you can use either VB or C# in ASP.NET Can someone correct me ? D:

Answer (score 2):

```
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["fname"]))
    {
        var name = Request.Form["fname"];
        Response.Write(name);
    }
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that `Response.Write` isn't really the sensible way to build content in ASP.NET these days...

Comment: Indeed. in PHP too (when using modern MVC Frameworks).

Answer (score 1):

Quickly written out of my head, it would look something like this:

```
protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = Request.Form["fname"];
    //Or with a TextBox
    string name = fnameTextBox.Text;

    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        Response.Write(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: `NameTextBox.Text` != `$_POST['fname']`

Comment: I'm using the drag and drop feature, text box thingy. @_@

Answer (score 1):

put this code in aspx page:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtfname" />
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnSubmit" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
```

and your aspx.cs page:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fname = txtfname.Text;
    //save to db or whatever code here
}
```